# How do I update Django database from field choices?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm developing a CRM using django and for my lead details I am trying to display my choices in the html form but also have it update the database when a new choice is selected and saved. Currently, I am able to display the choice that was selected upon lead creation, but I don't know how to allow the agent to change the choice and have that new choice update the database. I am still in the process of learning Django so theres still a lot i'm learning as i go.

```
views.py

class LeadDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "lead-details.html"
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "leads"
```

```
models.py

class Lead(models.Model):
    PROBLEM_LEAD = 'Problem Lead'
    PAY_TOO_FAR = 'Payments Too Far'
    PAY_TOO_SMALL = 'Payments Too Small'
    NPI = 'No Payment Information'
    ACTIVE = 'Active Deal'
    NO_DEAL = 'No Deal'

    choices_lead_status = [
    (PROBLEM_LEAD, 'Problem Lead'),
    (PAY_TOO_FAR,'Payments Too Far'),
    (PAY_TOO_SMALL,'Payments Too Small'),
    (NPI,'No Payment Information'),
    (ACTIVE,'Active Deal'),
    (NO_DEAL,'No Deal')
    ]
    choices_lead_owner = [
        ("Settlement, New",'Settlement, New'),
        ("Lead, Sales",'Lead, Sales'),
    ]

    lead_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=choices_lead_status, blank=True)
    lead_owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=choices_lead_owner, blank=True)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

```
html
# this displays the lead_owner but i also need it to iterate through the choices to allow proper selection
<div id="select">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-select">Lead </label>
        <select class="form-control" id="input-select" >
                <option>{{ leads.lead_owner}}</option>
                <!-- <option>Lead, Sales</option>
                <option>Settlement, New</option>
                <option>Corden, James</option>
                <option>Rower, Charles</option>
                <option>Has to be dynamic</option> -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to take into account and more than one way (as always) to accomplish it.  Here's my suggestions:

First, update your HTML to use Django tags with a for loop and iterate your lead_owner choices.  If the value matches the existing Lead_owner value, it's pre-selected:

```
<div id="select">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-select">Lead Owner</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="input-select" name="lead_owner">
            {% for choice in leads.choices_lead_owner %}
                {% if choice.0 == leads.lead_owner %}
                    <option value="{{ choice.0 }}" selected>{{ choice.1 }}</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ choice.0 }}">{{ choice.1 }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Submitting and updating the form can be done as such by inheriting from your LeadDetailView.  I included the imports as well:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django import forms

class LeadUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Lead
    form_class = LeadUpdateForm
    template_name = "lead-update.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lead_detail')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['leads'] = self.object
        return context
```

Now, you can create a new template and extend your existing HTML template like so by :

```
{% extends 'lead-details.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Update Lead</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps.

Edited for your question:

You could use the existing view and form.

You can edit the LeadDetailView to be something like this:

```
class LeadDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "lead-details.html"
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "leads"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = LeadOwnerForm(instance=context['leads'])
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lead = self.get_object()
        form = LeadOwnerForm(request.POST, instance=lead)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Lead updated successfully!")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Lead update failed.")
        return redirect('lead_detail', pk=lead.pk)
```

And, then the form can be adjusted like so:

```
{% block content %}
    {{ leads.first_name }} {{ leads.last_name }}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Another approach would be using Ajax, which is a bit more complicated but offers some solid benefits:

1. The page does not need to refresh upon submitting the form.  The backend will respond with Json too, which is something I prefer as your app evolves.
2. Ajax means that you'll ask for less data, typically, to be returned to the frontend.  It doesn't need to send back the entire template, but instead only the updated data or data you're choosing to return.

Ajax can be implemented with limited Javascript experience, but having JS experience allows you to do more with it.

I recommend getting to become familiar with implementing the above and then evolve your app to use Ajax, but that's me.  I also prefer to use function based views instead of class based views when starting with Django, so I can really see what's happening before it's mostly hidden in class based views.  But, Django is all about doing more with less, so learning CBV's out of the gate is not a bad thing at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. The html code for choices helped me a ton in that regard. 

For the LeadUpdateView() class, is the only way i can update a lead through another form? I currently have the lead information populate from the LeadDetailView, is there a way i can allow editing from there without populating a new form to update?

Comment: honestly thanks a lot. You've helped me understand a ton more. If you don't mind, do you have a discord where i could reach out in the event i have more questions? If not no worries I understand. Thanks a ton anyways

Comment: Hi Michael.  I'm happy to help! I'm not using discord at the moment, but it's on my radar.  If I can figure out how to send a chat message directly to you via StackOverflow, I'll gladly connect and share my contact info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again! I don't believe StackOverFlow has any messaging features. If you plan on joining any other social chatting platforms like discord, or something else. Please let me know, I'd love to connect! My discord ID is: Mike#7123